# IPC between Python & Java processes

Tags: java, python

I want to spawn a Java process from python script. And then read the stderr stream of the java process from the calling python script. Can this be done using pipes?

I try to spawn the java process from python script using python's win32 api's.
I create the java process having the **write end of pipe** by using the **win32process.CreateProcess()** method.

Then I wait on the java process to **signal** (i.e. finish) using **win32event.WaitForSingleObject()**. Then I try to read through the **read end of pipe** from the python script using **win32file.ReadFile()** method.

But I have no idea how to let the java program to communicate with the python script.
Do i need to use signal handler's in the java code? Kindly give an example...

Thank you,
Parag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for this, and then call `.communicate()` to send input, wait for finish, and then get stderr back.

The win32 APIs are both overkill and needless complexity for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Amber,But wont I need to take special care at the java side for this IPC...? I mean wont i need to use signal handler's there...?

Comment: +1, although I think the Win32 APIs are needlessly complex for basically anything one can do compared to the alternatives ;)